# I want to DM the owner of the server once the bot has been invited

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, chatbot

So I'm looking for a way to get my bot to message the owner of the server its been added too. After looking at lots of stackoverflow answers, they all looked similar to the following code:

```
client.on('guildCreate', guild =>{
    guild.author.send('Hello');
});
```

However, when I tried this and added the bot to another server, the bot not only crashed but I got the following error:

```
guild.author.send('Hello'); 
             ^ 

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
```

Can someone please help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this certainly means owner is undefined... Can you show us the code you are trying to make work? There's absolutely no use to show us random code you saw on internet but didn't try.

Comment: The code quoted by the error message is different to the code you provided. You need to provide a [mcve] showing code which reproduces the problem you describe, not one that is just similar to it.

Comment: I realised I had put in the wrong error message. This is the correct one

    guild.author.send('Hello');
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')

Answer (score 2):

You can get the owner by using two methods:

1. [`await guild.fetchOwner()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchOwner): This can be used to fetch the owner as a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) and an example is like this:

```js
const owner = await guild.fetchOwner()
```

2. [`guild.ownerId`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=ownerId): This can used to get the id of the owner of the server and then can be used to fetch the owner and an example is like this:

```js
const ownerId = guild.ownerId
const owner = guild.members.cache.get(ownerId)
```

Comment: `client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
    const ownerId = guild.ownerId
    const owner = guild.members.cache.get(ownerId)
    owner.send('Hi')
});`


So I tried this and I got the same error has before. 

    owner.send('Hi')
          ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')

Comment: The `owner` variable is a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember) and for the `.send()` function, you need a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/User), so you have to change the part where you send the message to `owner.user.send('hi')`

Comment: If you're grabbing the `ownerId`, instead of relying on the cache, it's probably better to fetch the member. Then again, `guild.fetchOwner()` does the same with less code, so that should be the preferred one. :)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I added the other option as well :)